# .gitignore including third party binaries/libraries

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I need to include libraries to be part of version control. These are binaries without source in the solution. At the same time, I want to exclude binaries and dll's generated by the build from the solution.

Additionally, what is the best way to handle nuget packages. Should it be part of the versioning.

I can use [.gitignore for VS](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) as a starting point.

I am using visual studio 2015 on windows 10 as a development environment

Comment: The general gist of it is to place `.gitignore` files which have general exclusion patterns, such as `*.exe`, in subdirectories rather than at the root, and/or match patterns inside subdirectories, e.g. `Release/**/*.exe`.

Comment: Thanks @MicroVirus